# Import package from another folder

Tags: java, package, directory

I want to import package1 into package2. How can I do that?

```
                           MyProject
       ________________________|______________
      /                                      |     
  folder1                               folder2      
     /                                     |                                      
package1                                package2
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:- add import statement into your package2

```
import folder1.package1.*;
```

> Make sure about access specifiers in java

[image]

Comment: Folder1 is not a package so it gives an error because it doesnt find the package.

Comment: actually package is nothing but the folder dude

Comment: make your package1 access specifier as per the your requirements

Comment: @Mr.Roshan package has nothing whatsoever to do with folder structure. This connection is purely incidental, becuase thats what IDE usually does.

Answer (score 0):

To use a public package member from outside its package, you must do one of the following:

- Refer to the member by its fully qualified name
- Import the package member
- Import the member's entire package

You can import the following:

- Interface
- Class
- Static field
- Static method

To import all the types contained in the `package1` in specific class/interface of `package2` use the following `import`:

```
import package1.*;
```

To import all the static members from the `package1` use:

```
import static package1.*;
```